# `None` in Keras loss function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I have a problem working with `Tensorflow` and `keras`. That problem we could explain in this way:

We have a model (convolutional neural network) which has output of the form `[None, 7, 7, 6]`. We have a function 'custom_loss'. This function has y_true and y_pred parameters. They are of the form `[7,7,6]`. When I compile it, I got error message: `TypeError: must be real number, not Tensor`. I suppose there is mistake when I call `y_pred[k][l][m]` and `y_true[k][l][m]` but I don't know how to fix this to include this `None` in `[None, 7, 7, 6]`. Please help.

**Update**: Here is the code

```py
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = 0
    for i in range(S*S):
        k, l = i%S, i//S
        first_part = 5* sum([(y_pred[k][l][m] - y_true[k][l][m])**2 for m in range(1,3)])
         second_part = 5 * sum([(math.sqrt(y_pred[k][l][m]) - math.sqrt(y_true[k][l][m])) ** 2 for m in range(3, 5)])
         third_part = 5* sum([(y_pred[k][l][m] - y_true[k][l][m])**2 for m in [0, 5]])
         if y_true[k][l][0] > 0.5:
             loss += first_part + second_part + third_part
        else:
            loss += 0.5 * (y_pred[k][l][0] - y_true[k][l][0])**2


     return loss
```

Comment: Please add your code to reproduce this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `keras` (and `TensorFlow` without eager execution) you cannot access the content of a tensor. Therefore, lines as

```
loss += 0.5 * (y_pred[k][l][0] - y_true[k][l][0])**2
```

will fail. You can try to use the eager execution mode of `TensorFlow` together with `keras` as explained [here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/G7PoqzY1Hck).

In general you should always try to express these things just with built-in functions of the `keras` backend or with `TensorFlow` operations. Just try to express your loss function using matrix/vector notation and then it is easier (maybe we can also help you) to express this in `keras`.

Comment: I think accessing the content of tensors works fine (at least slicing does). In combiantion with the for loop and if clause it cannot work. But I think the problem lies in a lack of understanding that with tensorflow the python code is about building the execution graph.

Answer (score 0):

When you wirte a loss function in keras (with tensorflow backend) it's for building your execution graph but not for execution directly.

You have to use tensorflow or keras backend function to define your loss function. If you compile your model keras (and tensorflow as backend) try to build your execution graph and therefore send tensors trough your loss function. the `math` package does not support tensors. Also is not possible to use `if` in your loss function since it's not derivable. Instead you could use a sigmoid function which is very close to a step function.